# Require.js specify variable instead of path in config

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Require.js takes an optional config. Is it possible to map a path to an existing variable?

```
require.config({
    "paths": {
        "jquery": "../my/path/to/jquery"
    }
});
```

However, there is a case where I don't actually need jquery but a library *thinks* it does. So I need to include jquery but it doesn't actually use it. Actually storing the jquery file is bloat. So I want to map `require("jquery")` to `function() {}`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set a `paths` for `jquery` for what you are trying to do. What you could do is add a fake jQuery module just before your call to `require.config`:

```
define('jquery');
```

This defines a `jquery` module that has an `undefined` value. **If** your premiss that you are using a library that requires jQuery but does not actually *use* it is true, then this will work.